# Margins defined for the ImageView inside a LinearLayout doesn't look same in all Android Devices

Tags: android, imageview, margins

In this piece of code, my two Image Views distinguished by id: Rot_Button_Down and Rot_Button_Up actually denote the two pieces of a lock which I have displayed individually. I wanted to add some animation of locking to it however I find that this piece of code doesn't work in other phones but a phone of 720p resolution. I am attaching the screenshot of how it looks like in a phone of 480p.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
>
<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/imageView"
    android:layout_width="50dp"
    android:layout_height="50dp"
    android:padding="3dp"
    android:scaleType="centerCrop"
    />
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:gravity="center_vertical"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:paddingLeft="5dp"
    android:onClick="changeLockInfo"
    >
<TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_width="265dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="center_vertical"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:layout_weight="0.85"/>
<ImageView
        android:id="@+id/Rot_Button_Down"
        android:layout_width="15dp"
        android:layout_height="15dp"
        android:adjustViewBounds ="true"
        android:src="@drawable/box"
        android:layout_weight="0.07"

        />
<ImageView
       android:id="@+id/Rot_Button_Up"
        android:layout_width="10dp"
        android:layout_height="10dp"
       android:adjustViewBounds ="true"
       android:layout_weight="0.08"
       android:src="@drawable/arc"
       android:layout_marginTop="-9dp"
       android:layout_marginLeft="-5dp"
       />
</LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

[image]

Comment: This is what it looks like in d480,720,1440 resolution phones. http://imgur.com/a/Bs6fL